# Using Stamen toner-lines tiles as ArcMap base map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tiles, basemap

Is it possible to use [stamen toner-lines tiles](http://maps.stamen.com/toner-lines/#12/37.7706/-122.3782) as a base map in ArcMap? If so, how are they added as a base map?

Several Stamen maps are available through [ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=cartogeek&title=Stamen%20basemaps), though not the toner-lines tiles.

[ArcBruTile](https://github.com/ArcBruTile/ArcBruTile/) can make external tiles usable as a base map in ArcMap, though the toner-lines tiles aren't one of the "[supported maps](https://github.com/ArcBruTile/ArcBruTile/blob/master/supported_maps.md)".

In 2013, Kenneth Field wrote a blog post about [using external tilesets in ArcGIS online maps](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/01/using-stamen-and-mapbox-tilesets-as-basemaps-in-arcgis-com/), though the interface for uploading datasets has changed and some of the interfaces/options are no longer presented when following the steps.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcBruTile you can add Stamen Toner Lines with option ArcBruTile -> Add TMS Service... -> Add Provider -> Stamen. Then you can select the service Stamen Toner Lines